# Works for 'edit', fails for 'new'... undefined method `association' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

Following the railscast #196 on nested forms... I have the following models:

```
class DealContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
  belongs_to :contact

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_contacts
  has_many :deals, through: :deal_contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_contacts, :allow_destroy => true

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_contacts
  has_many :contacts, through: :deal_contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_contacts, :allow_destroy => true
```

In my deals form I have this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12"><h4>Contacts Associated with this Deal</h4></div>
    <%= f.fields_for :deal_contacts do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'deal_contact_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="span1"><%= link_to_add_contact "Add", f, :deal_contacts %></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And deal_contact_fields just contains:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="span4">
        <%= f.association :contact, collection: Contact.all(order: 'contact_name'), label_method: :full_desc %>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <%= f.label :details, "Details " %>
        <%= f.text_field :details %>
    </div>
    <div class="span1" style="margin-top: 30px">
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This all works great for editing existing deals, however when I create a new one I get the following error:

```
undefined method `association' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fe6fba55840>
```

:-(

Answer (score 0):

`.association` is only available in [`simple_form` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations)

You'll have to use [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) to achieve what you want without that gem:

```
<%= f.collection_select :contact, Contact.all(order: 'contact_name'), :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for replying. Simple form is installed and this is working fine when I edit an existing deal, can add contacts to my hearts content. 

I will try switching to a collection_select however.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you had `simple_form` installed - perhaps your passing of the `builder` object (instead of `f`) is what's causing the issue?

Comment: You're currently passing `f: builder` to your partial. This is the `f.fields_for` builder, not the overall form builder object. Perhaps the `f.association` would be for the parent `f` object, not the `builder` object